# Markdown rendering taking a long time

Tags: r, markdown

I am using markdown and `knitr` to create HTML reports. For displaying tables, I use `xtable` and use `print(xtable(dataframe),type="html")`. To suit my needs better, I print HTML tags using `cat()` and use the chunk option `results = asis`.

The reports are fine except that ampersand is displayed as &amp. I am guessing that, maybe this is due to the fact that I have specified chunk option as asis.
So, this is what I did. This may be dirty, but I am kind of new to markdown.

```
fg = capture.output(print(xtable(dataframe),type='html'))
fg = gsub("&amp;","&",fg)
fg = gsub("&amp","&",fg)
fg[length(fg)] = "</TABLE>"     # because capture.output adds whitespaces 
                                # before the </TABLE> and markdown 
                                # parses it as a code block
cat(fg)
```

Now, this works. But if the dataset is huge, say `dataframe` has 1500 rows and 31 columns, the document takes a lot of time to render (about 9 hours). The rendering is pretty fast (2 - 3 mins) if I am not capturing the output and replacing `&amp` or `&amp;` for the same dataset.

Is there a better way to do this and/or speed this up?

Comment: Kudos for having patience of 9 hours. This definitely isn't the way to go. Have you checked which part takes so long? Capturing the output or gsubbing?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Capturing the output in markdown takes time.That step only. If I do the same thing in console it is near instant.